# How do I combine two database fields into a new field using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, phprunner

I'm using a variation of this script to combine two numeric fields into a third numeric field but I'm wanting to do the same thing with text. Namely creating a Full_Name field from a First_Name and a Last_Name field.  Here's the code...

Hoping someone can help me! Or maybe "keyup" function just doesn't work for non-number fields?

---

```
var ctrlFirst_Name = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'First_Name');
var ctrlLast_Name = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'Last_Name');
var ctrlName = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'Name');

function func() {
    ctrlName.setValue(ctrlFirst_Name.getValue() + (ctrlLast_Nme.getValue()));
};

ctrlFirst_Name.on('keyup', func);

ctrlLast_Name.on('keyup', func);
```

---

Thanks!
Eric

Comment: I would be tempted to use change rather than keyup. Less hektik activity

Comment: I've never used PHPRunner before but [according to the documentation](https://xlinesoft.com/phprunner/docs/control_object.htm), that event should be available. Can you explain more? Are you getting an error? Also, like @RiggsFolly said, `change` is probably the better method. If the field is rendered as a number widget with up/down arrows, `keyup` probably wouldn't fire for mouse users but `change` should fire for everyone.